# UITableViewAutomaticDimension breaking constraints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8, autolayout

I'm trying to use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, but I'm having trouble getting a cell to be full width and the correct height without causing `NSLayoutAutomaticSizeConstraint...` issues. If I turn auto size constraints off on the cell, it is not full width.

[image]

I have two buttons with horizontal and vertical constraints to the content view. They have a vertical spacing constraint between each other, and each button has a height constraint.

If I turn off `AutoResizingMask`, I get a not-full width cell. If I leave it on, I get layout constraint violations but things render correctly.

How can I get the behavior I'm looking for?

```
translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f856b169650 V:[UIButton:0x7f856b16a510'+(null)'(50)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f856b173dd0 UIButton:0x7f856b16a510'+(null)'.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f856b16bfa0.topMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f856b173e70 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f856b16bfa0.bottomMargin == UITextField:0x7f856b16c4f0.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f856b174520 V:[UIButton:0x7f856b16a510'+(null)']-(8)-[UITextField:0x7f856b16c4f0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f856b182a10 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f856b16bfa0(66)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f856b169650 V:[UIButton:0x7f856b16a510'+(null)'(50)]>
```

It actually looks like the width is set by

```
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    return CGSizeMake(320, 66);
}
```

If I don't set an intrinsic content size, I don't get any width or height.

Comment: 1) Are you creating your constraints and views in code? 2) In your view navigator, are you getting a yellow or red error?3) what else do you have in the view?

Comment: What layout constraint violations are you getting ?

Comment: @Spectravideo328 There are no yellow or red errors in IB, and all constraints are in IB.

Comment: @Lefteris I've added the constraint error message. I'm using a UITextField as if it were a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit:
Its definitely the two height constraints.  Try removing one, or lowering priority.

Comment: I set both height constraints to 999 instead of 1000. No autolayout exceptions. I don't understand but it works for me.

Comment: With the current constraints you have, you essentially have a fixed height cell.  Think about it this way, if the three vertical spacing constraints have a value of 5 each, and the button heights have a value of 10 each, the height is fixed at 35 (5 + 10 + 5 +10 +5).

Comment: Sure, and that's my intent. But I have a few cells each with different heights, and without auto dimension this would mean a bunch of code. The bottom spacer could be an "at least", but that's the only real wiggle room I want.

Comment: Im not certain about this, but I believe TableViewCell are by default to have flexible size.  I don't believe you can explicitly set the height in IB in iOS 8 on dynamic cells .  If you want explicit height, use heightForRowAtIndex and check cell identifier to set different height. When checking for cell identifier, don't call cellForRowAtIndex, but instead check your array or data source.

Answer (score 1):

AutoresizingMask on = allow the parents of this view to set the appropriate masks.

AutoresizingMask off = Do not allow the parents of this view to set the appropriate masks. I want to do them on my own.

If you create views in IB, their autoresizingMasks are set to No by default.

If you create views in code, their autoresizingMasks are set to Yes by default.

The fact that you get a not-full width cell (or really any behavior change) when you turn off AutoresizingMask means that likely a parent (in view hierarchy) of the cell or table is taking over and setting the constraints (which is not what you want).

Now the reason I think you are getting this not-full width cell is because of an annoying default in IB when you drag between view elements to set the constraints, where instead of tying the constraints to the top, bottom, etc..; IB ties it to the margin (different).

So you need to select your constraints from the "Document outline":

[image: Document outline]

**And then select one by one your constraints that tie to the border:**

[image: Constraint closed]

**And ensure that the "Relative to margin" is not checked.**

[image: Constraint open]

**If you use the summary constraints tab in the bottom right of IB (second from left), you can unselect the "Constraint to margins" when creating the constraints:**

[image: Constraints summary]

[image: Constraints optn]

Comment: @StefanKendall so as per above, are your top,right and left constraints set to the ContentView and not to the margin of contentView?

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem with this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

It tossed me a log about "unable to satisfy constraints" but there wasn't any constraint mislead so I've added the estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

And it fixed